# Android WiFi Direct requestGroupInfo returns zero size list

Tags: android, wifi-direct

No matter what I do, I am unable to receive information about the WiFi Direct group my device is connected to.

```
manager.requestGroupInfo(channel, new WifiP2pManager.GroupInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupInfoAvailable(WifiP2pGroup group) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Group info available " + group.getClientList());
            }
        });
```

always returns a clientList of size zero - even though I have an active p2P connection. I've tested this using Nexus 5 running 4.4.4 and RedMi 4 running 6.0. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that this method only works by the group owner. It's a pity this isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38488610/5894542